# Why are so many underscore lines in my file when to open it with Vim?

Tags: vimrc, multiple-lines

Everytime I opened a file with Vim,so many underscore lines in it such as below:

[image]

How can remove all the underscore lines ?

:colorsheme is desert.

The highlight output:

[image]

The terminal is LXTerminal.

```
echo $TERM
xterm-mono
```

Comment: Probably its your colorscheme: check the output of highlight. If you werent expecting underscores, but say italic instead, make sure TERM is configured correctly.

Comment: what terminal are you using? What is $TERM set to?

Comment: `xterm-mono` is most likely wrong. You may want to configure your terminal to perhaps use `xterm-256color`, but this may have some unwanted consequences, if LXTerminal is not fully xterm compatible.

Comment: Remark: you should not post the text just in image format. Depends on your terminal, there are different ways to copy from it.

Answer (score 0):

Set $TERM as `xterm-256color` in `.bashrc`,the underscore lines disappear.

Comment: More correctly, configure your terminal emulator to set TERM correctly.

Comment: Maybe accept your own answer after more than two years? Would prevent Community Bot from bumping the thing. Thank you.